# Getting No Data Available when using cp to copy a file (but file exists)

Tags: rsync, zfs, filesystem-corruption, cp

I am trying to copy a file with cp in Linux, and am getting an error: No Data Available

The file exists in my FS:

```
> ll formation_xrpu_personnalisation_27-09-2021\ 15\:33\:43.webm.mov 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 franck franck 103802972835 Mar 19 14:12 'formation_xrpu_personnalisation_27-09-2021 15:33:43.webm.mov'
```

It can even be played in vlc, so it is not really corrupted...

But when trying to copy it, I get an error:

```
> cp formation_xrpu_personnalisation_27-09-2021\ 15\:33\:43.webm.mov /tmp/
cp: error reading 'formation_xrpu_personnalisation_27-09-2021 15:33:43.webm.mov': No data available
```

rsync also detects the same error.
The file system is ZFS, if that matters.

What could be the cause of this and how to fix that file ?

Comment: Did you successfully play the whole video from start to finish? If not, how do you know it isn't corrupted?

Comment: Yes, the video plays to the end...

Comment: Do you really have 103GB space in `/tmp`?